# Removing Up Arrow and replacing with Down Arrow on button

Tags: jquery

Have a button with Show More with a down arrow. When user clicks the button the text changes to Show Less. I would like to remove the down arrow and add an up arrow.

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".show-more").click(function() {
        $(".more").slideToggle(400);
        return false
      })
    });

    $(".show-more").click(function() {
      $(".fade").fadeOut(150, function(){
        $(".fade").html($(".fade").html() == "Show Less" ? "Show More" : "Show Less");
        $(".fade").fadeIn()
      })
    });
```

CSS

```
.fade:after {
display: inline-block;
content: "\f091";
color: #2f90d5;
font: normal normal normal 14px/1 "Black Tie";
font-size: inherit;
text-rendering: auto;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
transform: translate(0, 0);
vertical-align: -5px;
padding-left: 10px;
```

}

Comment: Change the content?

Comment: You could change the class based on the toggle state

Comment: So I would need to remove the down arrow icon from .fade and add it to .show-more state, then remove it adding an up arrow with the .more state I suppose?